# Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE - assumed 'CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE'

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

i have http://www.idiotminds.com/login-with-facebook-in-codeigniter/
but i have error

```
> A PHP Error was encountered
> 
> Severity: Notice
> 
> Message: Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE - assumed
> 'CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE'
> 
> Filename: facebook/base_facebook.php
```

and i fix **CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,**
but not fixed

**but i have enable the php_curl**

**

```
cURL support enabled
cURL Information libcurl/7.24.0 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5

**
```

code

```
public static $CURL_OPTS = array(
    CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 10,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 60,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => 'facebook-php-3.2',
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
  );
```

it still not work
help me please
BIG THANKS

Comment: Need CURL_YOURCODE :) to be able t help you out here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE` is available only >= CURL version 7.10.8 and your CURL version is 7.24.0. Need to update CURL in order for that CONSTANT to be available. And support for this constant is only available for PHP>=5.3

Reference: http://gcov.php.net/PHP_5_3/lcov_html/curl/interface.c.gcov.php

Comment: thanks you, i will check now. if it not work i will reply continue

Comment: @Hanky: 7.24.0 seems to be greater then 7.10.8, no?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you may get latest curl. But you still have to install php-curl for php.
you chould check whether you have or not have it.

```
php -i |grep curl
//this will be return in your linux command line.
/etc/php/7.1/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
curl
```